# WPF .NET CORE 3.0 packing with Costura.Fody

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, fody-costura

When I migrate `WPF` Project to `.NET CORE 3.0` and try to pack assemblies using `Costura` I am getting the following error:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
>
> The program '[7980] CryptoBot.exe' has exited with code -2147450740 (0x8000808c).
>
> The program '[7980] CryptoBot.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

[image]

I found out that the reason for this behavior is that `Costura.Fody` doesn't properly handle `*.deps.json` file and that it should be 'removed or modified accordingly' by me.

There are two problems with this approach:

First: I am using `database.sqlite` file to store the data, removing `*.deps.json` will break references to `e_sqlite3.dll` and I don't know how to modify it properly (just add sqlite basic packages using nuget to an empty project if you want to check it out):

[image]

Second: Even if it did work it doesn't produce a single `.exe` file, but rather small `.exe` and big `.dll` containing the dependencies.

The desired result: I would like it to work exactly as it worked in `.NET Framework`, I want single `.exe` containing all the `.dll`s produced on `DEBUG` after pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `B`.

Alternatively, I also tried this:
`dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`
but it didn't seem to pack anything at all, it just placed all the `.dll`s in the `Release\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64` folder.

I PREFER that the app is packed into SINGLE `.exe` by using `Costura` and NOT anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to run `dotnet publish` with `--self-contained true` argument? Btw, which version of .net core 3 are you using?

Comment: Yes. Newest available non-preview. I would prefer that it is packed by `Costura` if possible though.

Comment: Costura is being deprecated https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/442 so you should probably stop using it